# Curl doesn't send cookie

Tags: php, cookies, curl

Curl doesn't send cookie from dev server, but when i run script from another server, it's works well. I can't understand what's wrong with dev server.

```
$curl=curl_init($request);

//$cook =  './cook/1.txt';
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cook);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cook)

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "departureCity=2; path=/;");

$out = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

$info:

```
Array
(

    [request_header] => GET /hotels/greece/showhotel/12_islands_villas_26 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Host: SITE
Accept: */*
Referer: SITE


)
```

there is now cookie data in header

Comment: First of all you have to remove trailing semicolon (`;`) in the cookie content. Furthermore, what is `path` in your cookie? If you mean it's a cookie attribute then it shouldn't be in a cookie content since it only has meaning when cookie is setting/updating, not reading (your case).

Comment: changes from `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIE, "departureCity=2; path=/;");`
to `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "departureCity=2");` But it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have to clarify what doesn't work. Show output of `$info` variable

Comment: i've found problem: curl was built without cookie support